# jQuery validate form with onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very big form with a lot of inputs inside. Some of those inputs are mandatory and I need to check them with jQuery 1.3.2. I am using NOT a submit button but a `<input type ="button">` -- I need to use that because I have to fire an ajax call when the button is clicked.

So what the code should do is:

1. Check if the mandatory fields are
   properly entered.
2. If the mandatory fields are NOT
   properly entered an image should be
   shown.
3. If the mandatory fields are correct
   then the ajax call can run.

As you may see some fields are repeated, so the code should be able to work also on ANY repeated/duplicate input (same Name and ID)

```
    <form action ="">
    <!-- First Author -->
    Author Name: <input type="text" id="AuthorName" name="authorNAMEinput">
<img src="error.png" style="display:none">
    Author DOB: <input type="text" id="AuthorDOB" name="authorDOBinput">
    Author Company: <input type="text" id="AuthorCompany" name="authorCompanyinput">
<img src="error.png" style="display:none">
    <!-- Second Author -->
    Author Name: <input type="text" id="AuthorName" name="authorNAMEinput">
<img src="error.png" style="display:none">
    Author DOB: <input type="text" id="AuthorDOB" name="authorDOBinput">
    Author Company: <input type="text" id="AuthorCompany" name="authorCompanyinput">
<img src="error.png" style="display:none">
    <!-- Third Author -->
    Author Name: <input type="text" id="AuthorName" name="authorNAMEinput">
<img src="error.png" style="display:none">
    Author DOB: <input type="text" id="AuthorDOB" name="authorDOBinput">
    Author Company: <input type="text" id="AuthorCompany" name="authorCompanyinput">
<img src="error.png" style="display:none">
    <input type ="button" id="authorbutton" name="authorbuttoninput">
    </form>
```

Now lets say that the mandatory fields are AuthorName and AuthorCompany.

I know how to proceed with the jQuery `$.get` and with the button onclick function, but I do not know how to BEFORE validate those mandatory fields and fire the `$.get` function onclick ONLY if the fields are properly entered. And I do not know how to make `<img src="error.png" style="display:none">` visible if the entered fields are not valide (make it visible for each NON-validate field).

Comment: A duplicate `id` is invalid mark-up, as an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document, a duplicate `name` is valid, as far as I know, but unless it's in the form `name[]` the last value submitted with that name will over-write any earlier values.

Comment: The user can add more Authors. How do I can do that if I do not duplicate the fields?

Comment: Are you using JQuery? If not, I advise you do. If yes, download the jQuery.validate plugin and read the documentation. It eases validation. Try [link](http://plugin.jquery.com)

Comment: You can use `name="authors[]"` which submits `authors` as an array, accessible to, for example, php (on the subsequent page/script) as `$_POST['authors']`

Comment: Yes I do. It is written in the question . I have already read the DOCS, but that does not help me. I am not a jQuery expert...

Comment: Use `class` then. @David Thomas is right. `id`s are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Ok I got it. But the problem remains. How do I achieve the above?

Comment: @David I think *submits as an array* is misleading. PHP does that magic, the browser will just submit it *as is*.

Comment: Can anyone help me with my question.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
 <form action ="">
    <!-- First Author -->
    Author Name: <input type="text" id="AuthorName1" name="authorNAMEinput">
     <img src="error.png" id="AuthorName1_error" style="display:none">
    Author DOB: <input type="text" id="AuthorDOB1" name="authorDOBinput">
    Author Company: <input type="text" id="AuthorCompany1" name="authorCompanyinput">
     <img src="error.png" id="AuthorCompany1_error" style="display:none">
    <!-- Second Author -->
    Author Name: <input type="text" id="AuthorName2" name="authorNAMEinput">
     <img src="error.png" id="AuthorName2_error" style="display:none">
    Author DOB: <input type="text" id="AuthorDOB2" name="authorDOBinput">
    Author Company: <input type="text" id="AuthorCompany2" name="authorCompanyinput">
     <img src="error.png" id="AuthorCompany2_error" style="display:none">
    <!-- Third Author snipped -->
    <input type ="button" id="authorbutton" name="authorbuttoninput">
</form>
<script>
  $('#authorbutton').click(function() {
    var valid = true;
    var requiredFields = ['AuthorName1','AuthorCompany1','AuthorName2','AuthorCompany2'];
    for(var i = 0; i < requiredFields.length; i++) {
      var val = $('#'+requiredFields[i]));
      if (!val) {
        $('#'+requiredFields[i]+'_error').show();
        valid = false;
      } else
        $('#'+requiredFields[i]+'_error').hide();
    }
    if (valid) {
      // ajax stuff
    }
  });
</script>
```